# localNotification in corddova not working

Tags: cordova, localnotification

I'm using cordova 4.0.0 , iOS SDK 7.1 through CLI.

I added:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git && cordova prepare
```

Then in `config.xml` I added

```
gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification"
```

Then in `index.js` I added

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       window.plugin.notification.local.hasPermission(function (granted) {
            console.log('Permission has been granted: ' + granted);
       });

       var now = new Date().getTime(),
        _60_seconds_from_now = new Date(now + 60*1000);

       window.plugin.notification.local.add({
         id:      1,
         title:   'Reminder',
         message: 'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
         repeat:  'weekly',
         date:    _60_seconds_from_now
      });
```

After this no error was shown on Xcode , no notification was created and all other functionalities in my app were disabled.

Kindly tell me what error I would have committed or I have missed any steps. I have used many plugins to create local notifications but none them are working..

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, looking into it. Will notify you if I find anything. The error is that plugin does not get installed properly. It says could not choose notification of undefined

Comment: Well I got the solution . The point is the plugin just gets available at $(document).ready , So rather than calling its methods just after $(document).ready  we can call them on click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try these and it should work.

- Create a Cordova project
- Add plugin  https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git

Note:- Do not use the `&& cordova prepare`

- Add a platform
- Now build it ( Cordova build)

The `cordova build` command is a shorthand for the following

```
$ cordova prepare ios
$ cordova compile ios
```

Note:- There is **no** need of explicitly adding plugin details:

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
```

And it should work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . Well I got the solution . The point is the plugin just gets available at $(document).ready , So rather than calling its methods just after $(document).ready we can call them on click of a button.